# GetCommandLine(): unable to pass multiline arguments from batch-file (GCC-Compiler)

Tags: c++, command-line, argv

Unable to pass multi-line arguments from batch-file using the ^ symbol (GCC-compiler).

myapp.exe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  printf("%s", GetCommandLine());

}
```

run.bat (execute myapp with multi-line arguments)

```
myapp.exe ^
aaa ^
bbb ^
ccc
```

Actual output is:

```
myapp.exe ^
```

Expected output is:

```
myapp.exe aaa bbb ccc
```

How to get all lines?

I have tested some other applications and multi-line arguments with ^ symbol works as expected there. How it works?

Comment: I surprised that this compiles as `GetCommandLine` requires one of the MS-Windows header files, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The c++ include file is < cstdio >

Comment: Is the `^` the very last character on the line?  If not it won't work.

Comment: Your code works fine. Just make sure you put the `'^'` (circumflex) as the very last character when splitting input over multiple lines. Otherwise, just put all arguments on a single line. You can call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) to split the command line up into an `argv` style array.

Comment: '^' - is the very last character on each line. GetCommandLine() returns only first line with '^'-character at the end. (GCC-compiler)

Comment: Tested in VC++ and it works. This is compiler-specific. It seems GCC is bugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. Just make sure you put the `'^'` (circumflex) as the very last character when splitting input over multiple lines. That looks to be the only reason your code would be failing.

For example, using your code on Win7, the following works fine:

```
c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\getcmdline.exe my ^
More? dog ^
More? has ^
More? fleas
bin\getcmdline.exe  my dog has fleas

c:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\getcmdline.exe ^
More? aaa ^
More? bbb ^
More? ccc
bin\getcmdline.exe  aaa bbb ccc
```

Otherwise, just put all arguments on a single line and access them through `argv[x]` as normal.

You can also call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) to split the command line up into an `argv` style array. That is another alternative for splitting the commands into `LPWSTR*` format.

Comment: '^' - is the very last character on each line. I have tested on Win10, and this doesn't work. GetCommandLine() returns only first line with '^'-character at the end. (GCC-compiler)

Comment: Why are you using the `gcc` compiler? `GetCommandLine()` isn't a C standard library command and will most likely fail if run within WSL due to differing `CRLF` and `LF` line endings. If you are compiling with `gcc` in WSL, then forget about `GetCommandLine()` and iterate over `argv` in a standard manner. If you want to use `GetCommandLine()`, then compile with `cl.exe` (the VS compiler), e.g. `cl /nologo /Wall /wd4100 /wd4255 /wd4668 /wd4820 /wd4996 /Ox /Foobj/getcmdline /Febin/getcmdline /Tc getcmdline.c`. It will work fine then. Type `cl /?` for a list of compiler options.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Tested in VC++ and it works. This is compiler-specific.